# Updating Foreign Key dependent record using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2012

I am working on application with more than 50 tables with a large amount of data.

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Parent { pID int (PK), pName varchar(30) }
```

and

```
Child { pID int (FK), cName varchar(30) }
```

Here is my query:

```
using(MyDBContext ctx = new MyDBContext())
{
    Child ch = ctx.Childs.Where( c => c.pID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    ch.cName = "ABCDEF";
    ctx.SubmitChanges();   //  <--- Executes but nothing changes...
}
```

I have tried multiple existing values but `ctx.SubmitChanges()` doesn't work when updating child record. Any workaround?

Comment: I think, you need to add the changes of "ch" to "ctx" and then you must call "SubmitChanges". In your query, you create "ch" as Child locally and you change the "cName" of the local Child "ch". With "SubmitChanges" you add some new changes of the ctx, but you don't change "ctx", you only change the local Child "ch". I hope you know what I mean. ;)

Comment: No! that's not the issue. What I have learned is:First, there must be something to hold data from Database. So, that's the "ch". Second, I have search over internet and the <b>FK</b> issue is there with LinqToSQL. <br>Later on, I switched to Entity 6.0 Data Models but that completely removed the inter-connected main table from the auto-generated view. So, useless in my case.

Comment: is it Entity Freamwork 6?

Comment: @Vecchiasignora: Linq to SQL Classes.

Answer (score 0):

The table could not be updated, because it doesn't have primary key. SubmitChanges will not work if you dont have primary key on your table(child). Set primary key on Child table like this

```
Child { ID int (PK), pID int (FK), cName varchar(30) }
```

and may everething will by ok

Comment: I know, adding PK will resolve this issue, but that's not required.

Comment: I have figured out solution by myself... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself. I have created an SQL Procedure which updates the record. Here is, how I did it:

```
create procedure UpdateChildName
(
    @pID int,
    @name varchar(30)
)
AS
BEGIN
    update Child set cName = @name where pID = @pID;
END;
```

Linq to SQL Part:

```
using(MyDBContext ctx = new MyDBContext())
{
    ctx.UpdateChildName(1, "ABCDE");
    ctx.SubmitChanges();         //   <--- Now working great.
};
```

Now, I don't have any issue with FK or PK dependency... :)